# How to specify exact field in generic?

Tags: typescript

```js
type Some = {field: 'add'} | {field:'remove'};

function add(value: Some) {} // Where value.field === 'add'
function remove(value: Some) {} // Where value.field === 'remove'
```

Is there a way to make functions `add` and `remove` receive values with exact field='add' or field='remove' values?

I use zod infer on union and want to make the function receive only one type from the union without dividing them to different types.

Comment: Not sure if I understand your question correctly. You can either define a more specific explicit type e. g. using `Extract` as shown on [this playground](https://tsplay.dev/mAaLRm) or you could runtime check the argument. E. g. with a type predicate as shown on [this playground](https://tsplay.dev/mpozaN). Does either of the two options work you?

Comment: • There are no [generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) here; could you [edit] the title to use a more appropriate term? Do you just mean "union"?  • Does knowledge of zod matter for this question? • The right thing to do given this code is to start with each piece and then combine them in a union afterward. If that isn't feasible then you might want to make a [mre] that motivates the existence of the union in the first place.

Comment: (See prev comment)  • If you *do* need the union, then again, given this code, you should just write `{field: 'add'}` and `{field: 'remove'}` inside `add` and `remove`.  Even something like `Extract` is overkill because you'd end up writing `Extract<Some, {field: "add"}>` which is more complicated than just `{field: "add"}`. Again, you might want to flesh out your [mre] to motivate it more. Maybe your union members have more properties in them?

Comment: Thanks guys. Extract is exactly what I needed. Just couldn't find it :)

Comment: It makes sense that you need `Extract`, but the example doesn't motivate it. Could you please [edit] to make it more reasonable to use `Extract`, say by adding more fields to the union members in `Some`?  Even `{field: "add", foo: string} | {field: "remove, bar: number}` would help, since then `Extract<Some, {field: "add"}>` will give you a result other than just `{field: "add"}`.  And then maybe @Behemoth wants to write up an answer.

Comment: @jcalz I agree that using `Extract` is syntactically more complicated and has the side effect you mentioned. However, I think it has the advantage that it is constrained with the original union `Some`. If a property in `Some` changes you will get according compiler errors on the function parameter types. Object literals won't alarm you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Extract`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#extracttype-union) to infer your desired object types from the Union `Some` like so:

```
type Some = { field: "add" } | { field: "remove" };

declare function add(value: Extract<Some, { field: "add" }>): void; 
//                   ^? value: { field: "add"; }
declare function remove(value: Extract<Some, { field: "remove" }>): void; 
//                      ^? value: { field: "remove"; }
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play#code/C4TwDgpgBAyg9gW2gXigbygMwJYQDYAmAXFAEQCGBBpUAvlAD7pa6EmkBOECcAbhDVoBuAFAiCEAMZ5yXLAFcAdpODY4iqJQIAKXuTzyIJAKIAPYB3IqAPPCQAaZjnzEyWwQD4AlCV5xsBEJQIgD0IVARkVHRUQB6APziUjJymEoqahpcPPy6+oYm5pY2dhCOGM5sZNl8AnTevv6BwWExbe1QCWJa2miVrpzctaS0XqHhEQB+09NQACrg0ADkgzkCS1DYAM5QinDAmltb2ADmiuQARnjQwHBQoJBQK+5LQA)

However, this has the side effect than it might extract more than just that one property `field`. If Some is something like

```
type Some =
  | { field: "add"; property2: string }
  | { field: "remove"; property2: number };
```

there might be additional unexpected properties extracted:

```
declare function add(value: Extract<Some, { field: "add" }>): void;
declare function remove(value: Extract<Some, { field: "remove" }>): void;

add({ field: "add" });
//   ~~~~~ Property 'property2' is missing in type '{ field: "add"; }' ...
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play#code/C4TwDgpgBAyg9gW2gXgFBSgHygbygMwEsIAbAEwC4oAiAQzLOoG4owAnOSN0AJioGdgbQgDsA5lAC+6LLgLFyVamwgI4ANwjNWHLryoiArggBGENlKapUZCAGMStFQUMi7wQnBFR6ZABTqtCSGEFQAogAeQrTuADzwSAA0ckSklDS+1FIAfACUVOpwhGRWtg5O0Piu7p7eKmqaAUEh4VFsMcDxiBDJeKmKNPUaWjn5UIXFVqi+fn0K6XQMWZK5VgD0axhQAH67u1AACrrmoFAA5OycJyA8Z1CE-FAID-yiEqJQoJDnc2lKmSxJHcAHSg1BAA)

---

The other option is to use [object literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html). This is more straightforward but you lose the constraint to the original union `Some`. If you decide to rename `field` in the future the compiler won't warn you about that since the object literal type has no connection to `Some` anymore.

```
type Some = { field: "add" } | { field: "remove" };

declare function add(value: { field: "add" }): void;
//                   ^? value: { field: "add"; }
declare function remove(value: { field: "remove" }): void;
//                      ^? value: { field: "remove"; }
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play#code/C4TwDgpgBAyg9gW2gXigbygMwJYQDYAmAXFAEQCGBBpUAvlAD7pa6EmkBOECcAbhDVoBuAFAiCEAMZ5yXLAFcAdpODY4iqJQIAKXuTzyIJDDnzEyWwQEoSvONgKiA9E6hv3Hzx4B6AfnFSMnKYSipqGlw8-Lr6hsYsZuyRfAJ0NlB2Ds6uXrl5fiJAA)

Personally, I find this more error prone and therefore prefer using `Extract`.